# Exporting image from highchart with phantomjs

Tags: highcharts, phantomjs

I want to export an image from *Highchart* with *Phantomjs* but executing the following command returns an empty SVG image.

```
phantomjs rendrer.js
```

I made sure to inject all highchart js files at the top but the console.log call at the end returns null.

```js
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');

// load JS libraries
page.injectJs("jquery-3.4.1.min.js");
page.injectJs("https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js");
page.injectJs("https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js");
page.injectJs("https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export- 
    data.js ");

    // chart demo
    var args = {
      width: 600,
      height: 500
    };

    var svg = page.evaluate(function(opt) {
      $('body').prepend('<div id="container"></div>');
      var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
          type: 'column'
        },

        title: {
          text: 'Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender'
        },

        xAxis: {
          categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },

        yAxis: {
          allowDecimals: false,
          min: 0,
          title: {
            text: 'Number of fruits'
          }
        },

        plotOptions: {
          column: {
            stacking: 'normal'
          }
        },

        series: [{
          name: 'John',
          data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]

        }]
      });

      return chart.getSVG(opt);
    }, args);
    console.log(svg)
    // Saving SVG to a file
    fs.write("demo.svg", svg);
    // Saving diagram as PDF
    page.render('demo.pdf');

    phantom.exit();
```

Comment: I can see that you are using standalone PhantomJS. There is a dedicated solution based on PhantomJS for Highcharts that allows to export charts. You will find more information here: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server.

Comment: Rephrased and formatted code.

Comment: Thank you for your response,
I have clone this project in your link, but i coudn't add my highcart data and i didn't find a way to use this solution.
i have execute my code but the problem is that the return svg is emty
can you help please.

Comment: @YassineAbida Could you please provide us with command along with chart options that you are using to export a chart?